# How to fix 'warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]'?

Tags: embedded, compiler-warnings, truncate, integer-overflow

I created these macros to execute an arithmetic operation:

```
#define CLK_FREQ        8U
#define I2C_BMP180      I2C1
#define I2C_CLK_FREQ    CLK_FREQ

#define I2C_GET_CCR_SM(i2c_speed) (500000U * I2C_CLK_FREQ / ((unsigned int)(i2c_speed)))
```

After compilation, I get this warning:

**src\main.c:11:35: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]**

```
#define I2C_GET_CCR_SM(i2c_speed) (500000U * I2C_CLK_FREQ / ((unsigned int)i2c_speed))
                                  ^
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `1000000UL` instead of `1000000U` (unsigned long instead of unsigned).

Comment: @kkrambo I already tried. It keeps showing the warning.

Comment: @Clifford It's a STM32F103C6T6 microcontroller.

Comment: You have edited the code in the question to reflect answers (a bad practice as it makes the answered look ridiculous), but now the code in the first fragment is not the same as that in the error message, so how can we trust it?  You would do well to roll back the question to that to which existing answers apply.  The comments on those answers suffice as feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is mixed both `signed` and `unsigned` parameter. Please try following:

```
    #define CLK_FREQ        8U
    #define I2C_CLK_FREQ    CLK_FREQ

    #define I2C_GET_CCR_SM(i2c_speed) (1000000U * I2C_CLK_FREQ / (2U * (unsigned int)i2c_speed))
```

The key here is that the result should be `unsigned` and therefore it is better to convert all to `unsigned`. Compiler might have problem on knowing whether you want a use `signed` or `unsigned`

Comment: Also `i2c_speed` should be in parentheses to avoid operator precedence issues - the cast will otherwise only apply to the first operand if `i2c_speed` is an expression rather than a single variable or literal.

Comment: @ThongDT I already tried your method but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure type/sign agreement in your macro, and also coerce the `i2c_speed` expression over which you have no control:

```
#define CLK_FREQ        8u
#define I2C_CLK_FREQ    CLK_FREQ

#define I2C_GET_CCR_SM(i2c_speed) ((500000U * I2C_CLK_FREQ) / (unsigned)(i2c_speed))
```

Comment: I made those changes but the problem is still there. I edited my question to show the changes.

Comment: Add details of the compiler/version  you are using (not the IDE), and the compiler settings.  Cannot reproduce.  It may be context specific - include the code where this macro is used too